# MATLAB - How to print a string as a numeric?

Tags: matlab

I have this code that I wanna run:

```
%This program is for Euler-Cauchy Second Order%
disp('Euler-Cauchy Second Order')
n=1;
syms eqn ypp
eqn= input ('y``:  ');
x=input('x0:  ');
y=input('y0:  ');
yp=input('y`:  ');
h=input('step:  ');
disp('n    x      y        y`        y``')
solve (ypp==eqn,ypp);
a=char(ans);
fprintf('%1.1f %1.1f  %2.5f  %2.5f  %2.5s \n',n,x,y,yp,a)
```

But I wanna display my 'a' as a numeric with 2 whole numbers and 5 decimal places like the others. Obviously, the one above doesn't work in fprintf. I've tried converting a into double but it returns with a 'NaN', I don't know what else to do. Please help!

Comment: Is there any other problem in your code? E.g. what are these `x`, `y`, `yp` and `h` doing in your code? Can you explain your code in more details? Moreover you can escape the single quotes as `'y'''':  '`, `'y'':  '`, etc.

Comment: I'm doing a Numerical Method of Euler-Cauchy for Second Order Differential Equations. I've tried converting them using char and then convert them again using str2num and it works, but it doesn't print them using fprintf.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [str2num](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
str2num(a)
```

Other data type conversion can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-type-conversion.html).

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. it returns with []
edit:
Tried it again, 'a' seems to be a sym variable and converts the equation into 8bit integers.
edit:
Tried it again. Now it returns the value of the character a instead of the numeric value.

Comment: What purpose does 'a' got in your code? When you change the data type, you also have to change the fprintf, '%s' to string and char type, '%d' for integers.